# Manage multiple hardware and OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-xp, hardware

I'm new at windows management, before I've worked only with Apple Macs.

Now I am at a company that has almost 100 computers with different boards, brands, different hard drives, etc.. in different locations, it's a nightmare!

Right now the company have also different domains.

I want to unify everything.

How can i manage the software and windows updates?

I have windows server 2008.
Can I use Group Policy?

If yes, where can i find more information?

Answer (score 1):

For software, start by reviewing the needs of everybody, and standardize on a few profiles with the same operating system and other software. Define policies on updating, antivirus, ... Later on see how to place everything under a common roof (the whole Windows domains stuff).

For hardware, you could evaluate a contract for planned machine renewal with some of the bigger vendors. That way you'll have reasonably up to date machines with uniform configuration in the user's hands in a few years, and that maintains itself.

[No Windows use for a round of years now, so this is mostly generic advice.]

Comment: For Software, i am migrating emails to Google Apps, but first i have to  change the internal network and some cables and internet connection. I still have HUBs from Intel.... Then i have more than 16 mini access applications... but changing the ERP, problem solved. But will cost me $$$....

The hardware is a problem because 2/3 of the machines just need RAM and a new harddrive, the problem is that almost all the machines are white label, asus, asrock, ecs, forxconn.... 
In my best dreams if i can change the ERP for a browser application, ubuntu + chrome and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to take a look at [Dell KACE](http://www.kace.com/).  It's not free, but is one of the best unified management / configuration / deployment platforms for windows management.

Alternatively to that, there's built-in tools in Windows Server 2008, such as Windows Deployment Services (WDS).

Comment: But is expensive for 100 computers.
I will call to see if they have a solution for smaller companies.
http://www.zdnet.com/dell-kace-caters-to-it-with-added-os-support-on-management-appliances-7000004722/

Comment: Dude.. That's List Price.  Nobody pays that.

Comment: Meraki have a free solution. it's not perfect. But it's free http://meraki.cisco.com/products/systems-manager